# Is it possible to use node to get video width and height without using ffmpeg?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, html5-video

I would like to know if it is possible to use node to get video width and height in pixel without using/installing a ffmpeg as a separate executable (which should be installed outside `npm install`).

For example a simple solution where file properties width/height could be reasonable in my case.

Thanks

Comment: How many video container formats and codecs do you need to support? And how confident are you in being able to "decode" the required information from such a diverse range of possible binary inputs?

Comment: You could use module `fluent-ffmpeg` from node, but unfortunately it requires `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe`

Comment: or maybe exits a version ffmpeg  compiled in js?

Comment: Yes! It is possible. You just need to write the code.